# Chart.js not showing data when pass dynamic labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I am using time scale and passing moment date values to the labels. The time scale expects either an integer (number of milliseconds since epoch), a Date object, a moment.js object for label values.

I have a dynamic array of labels when I pass this to the charts.js "Labels" object after converting that array into the comma split quotes then the data is not displaying on the graph.

```
        data: {
        labels: JSON.stringify(newDateArray),
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            data: [2, 3],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
            fill: false,
        }]
    }
```

But when I pass the output of the above array statically then the graph starts working correctly.

```
        data: {
        labels: ["2020-02-25T19:00:00.000Z","2020-02-27T19:00:00.000Z"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            data: [2, 3],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
            fill: false,
        }]
    }
```

I tried different ways for converting JS array into the comma split string and then passing that dynamic labels i.e (["'" + newDateArray.join("','") + "'"]) but didn't work anyone.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kayani/n39e6m4w/3/) containing the complete charts.js code.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: don't need to use `JSON.stringify`,just set `labels:newDateArray`.

Comment: @LiuYu Please post this in the answer with short detail so that I can mark it as answer, Thank you!

Comment: I just know `labels` should be an `array` like the [sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/?h=labels) . I can't find the `"rule"` or the api explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing just array to the labels instead of converting array to the comma split strings solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

'<%-JSON.stringify(vCenterSpace)%>' is coming from node.js controller, I also spent time in figuring this out.. working code sample for reference

```
                               <script>
                                   
                                    var vCenterSpaceData = ('<%-JSON.stringify(vCenterSpace)%>')
                                    var vCenterSpaceParsedData = JSON.parse(vCenterSpaceData)
                                    
                                    const formChartData = []
                                    const formChartLabels = []
    
                                    for(key in vCenterSpaceParsedData)
                                    {
                                        formChartData.push(vCenterSpaceParsedData[key]["Percentage"])
                                        formChartLabels.push(vCenterSpaceParsedData[key]["Date"])
                                    }
                                    //alert(formChartLabels)
                                    
                                    const zschart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chartjs-0"), {
                                        "type": "line",
                                        "data": {
                                            "labels": formChartLabels,
                                            "datasets": [{
                                                "label": "Usage in %",
                                                "data": formChartData,
                                                "fill": false,
                                                "borderColor": "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                                                "lineTension": 0.1
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        "options": {}
                                    });
                                </script>
```